# Meshlab texture parameterization tool makes black texture

Tags: meshlab

I am having some problems with the texture parameterization tool in Meshlab 2016. Every time I run it I get a black texture.

I have imported a model from VisualSFM and I have created a mesh from this and it appears that Meshlab knows there is a texture attached. There is a list of images in the layers view, but when I run the tool the whole mesh goes black and the exported texture is also black. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you double click on any of the images from that list in layers view? You should get a nice overlay of the image on top of your model (properly aligned with the image content).

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem and figured out that it is **necessary to save the VisualSFM files in the same folder** in which the pictures are. Maybe you made the same mistake as I made and saved the VisualSFM files in a second folder or something.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is still relevant...

I noticed that when I save a project and look at the .mlp file if the center pixels are not an integer I get a black texture. If I manually change them to an integer the texture parameterization works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my 2016 iMac, both on Windows and OSX and it generally occurs when the screensaver / sleep mode kicks in while something is being processed. To see if something has gone wrong, double click one of the images as mentioned above, if it shows the temporary texture this problem has occurred. If it happens once it never recovers so, **you'll need to restart meshlab and reload the `bundle.rd.out` and `list.txt`, along with your mesh**.